# Boostrap problema con posicionamiento

Tags: bootstrap

Hola como estan? me dieron una tarea y vengo hace horas rompiendome la cabeza y no se como resolverlo llegué a este codigo pero no me queda como en el prototipo:

```
<div class="row w-75 align-items-center mt-5">
            <div class="col-sm-8 h-100">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <img src="../../../assets/img/Mask Group 31.png">
                    <h5>Product page stars widget</h5>
                    <p>Shows stars on the product page. When clicked, jumps to the reviews widget</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <img src="../../../assets/img/Group 1514.png">
                    <h5>Product page stars widget</h5>
                    <p>Shows stars on the product page. When clicked, jumps to the reviews widget</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <img src="../../../assets/img/Group 1516.png">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img src="../../../assets/img/Group 1515.png">
            </div>
        </div>
```

El prototipo: [image: Prototipo]

Answer (score 0):

Talvez podrías explicar mejor lo que quisieras lograr, hice este ejemplo, talvez te sea de utilidad, tendrías que agregarlo en tu documento para hacer la prueba
Saludos

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="height: auto; background-color: cadetblue;">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 bg-secondary">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit corrupti illum dolor quidem laudantium dolorem officiis temporibus amet minus quas explicabo, debitis sapiente beatae repellat nesciunt, doloremque velit suscipit facere, natus aliquid dolores cumque? Assumenda laudantium fugiat voluptate. Dolore, magni, tenetur! Tenetur quam, officia magnam odit fugit, accusamus dolorum a. Amet consequuntur cum perspiciatis saepe nulla aperiam laudantium ipsum officiis reiciendis, exercitationem nisi, vel illum quidem quaerat quas corrupti. Ullam asperiores ratione sequi vel reprehenderit quis eaque architecto id ad.
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 bg-primary">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non quos, perspiciatis dolores id minus nemo totam dicta aliquam inventore quas repudiandae fuga maxime odio explicabo recusandae ducimus necessitatibus rem, accusamus placeat ratione. Laborum atque, reiciendis expedita distinctio consequatur architecto doloremque earum nihil nostrum repellendus? Quod eius repudiandae ut doloribus optio natus porro error blanditiis soluta deleniti dolores quos quibusdam laborum omnis, iusto dicta modi quam similique sunt rerum at et! Ducimus repellat quos commodi neque nobis quasi iure perferendis tenetur!
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 bg-danger align-self-center">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus, ullam pariatur distinctio atque illum voluptatibus repellendus dignissimos tenetur perferendis voluptatem deserunt vel id quam repellat cupiditate nam. Omnis minima vitae, dolorum dolore veritatis ducimus soluta quae minus, corporis modi rem fugiat neque commodi perferendis sunt accusantium dolores reprehenderit aliquam dignissimos nostrum sit eligendi inventore. Eius aut eum labore ut voluptatem.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 h-100 bg-dark"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```